# Serving a new locale under a new domain name in an Rails 4 I18n app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, routes, unicorn, rails-i18n

I have developed an I18n Rails 4 app served behind nginx and unicorn. The different locales are set in the url.

`http://example.com/   => English default language
http://example.com/fr => French`

And I’m using the route_translator gem to translate the routes.

I need now to add a new locale, but this time I would like it to use a different domain name.

`http://example.de => German`

What would be the best way to do it?